# Haartraining Error " One of arguments' values is out of range (Negative or too largeargument of cvAlloc function)"

Tags: opencv

The txt file showing where the negatives are is as shown below:

```
F:\SampleTraining\posdata\0.jpg 
F:\SampleTraining\posdata\1.jpg 
F:\SampleTraining\posdata\2.jpg 
....
F:\SampleTraining\posdata\405.jpg
```

i use this code:

```
haartraining.exe -data xml -vec pos.vec -bg negdata.txt -nstages 6  -minhitrate 0.5 -maxfalsealarm 0.3 -npos 405 -nneg 957 -w 30 -h 30 -nonsym -mem 2048
```

negative image txt file be

```
F:\SampleTraining\negdata\0.jpg
F:\SampleTraining\negdata\1.jpg
F:\SampleTraining\negdata\2.jpg
...
F:\SampleTraining\negdata\958.jpg
```

I use python3.7 and opencv3.4

Comment: Does it crash immediately or after some stages? use the traincascade binary, the haartraining binary is deprecated. And your chosenn number of positives pet stage must be smaller than the number of available samples, because you will lose up to (1-minHitRate)*numPos samples in each stage.